# Search using php isset not working

Tags: php, html

```
if (isset($_GET['k']))
{

    $k=$_GET['k'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM `upload` WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%$k%'  ";

 @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("error");
 mysql_select_db("lol") or die ("error");

 $query= mysql_query($query);
  $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
 if($numrows >0)
 {
    while ($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {

    $keywords=$row['keywords'];
    $name2=$row['name2'];
    $URL=$row['URL'];
    echo "<h2><a href='$URL'>$name2</a></h2><br/><br/>";

    }
 }
 else
 echo "no result found";
 }
 else
 {
    echo "please enter some value in search";
 }

?>
```

I am making a simple search engine The issue is that if don't pass a value in search bar it shows all the results from database .To make it correct I use ISSET but it is not working plz help me me for this. Here is the attached code

Comment: What you are expecting when there is no search keyword?

Comment: did you try post method??

Comment: yesi i try post method but it didnot work. it should print enter some value..should not access to access to the database??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Html:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="k" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And secondly the PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['k']) && ($_POST['k'] != ""))
{

    $k=$_POST['k'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM `upload` WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%$k%'  ";

 @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("error");
 mysql_select_db("lol") or die ("error");

 $query= mysql_query($query);
  $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
 if($numrows >0)
 {
    while ($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {

    $keywords=$row['keywords'];
    $name2=$row['name2'];
    $URL=$row['URL'];
    echo "<h2><a href='$URL'>$name2</a></h2><br/><br/>";

    }
 }
 else
 echo "no result found";
 }
 else
 {
    echo "please enter some value in search";
 }

?>
```

Comment: still the same issue when i just click on the submit button without using any keyword it shows all the results from database.but it has to echo "please enter some value in search"??? plz help me

Comment: I've eddited my post - the HTML and the PHP code. So you can copy it and use it.

Comment: thank you so much now its working and I understand what was the issue

Comment: Please approve my answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Yes it help me but how to improve ur answer ??

Comment: Under the votes of my answer there is a tick - button for approving the answer.

Comment: oh i got it.. now i did it